# uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details

Tags: android

05-16 18:31:00.526 16526-16526/com.works.adeogo.doctor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.works.adeogo.doctor, PID: 16526
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Boolean to type com.works.adeogo.doctor.model.TempMessage
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
        at com.works.adeogo.doctor.TestChatActivity$4.onChildAdded(TestChatActivity.java:362)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzbt.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6236)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)

Code:
05-16 18:31:00.526 16526-16526/com.works.adeogo.doctor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.works.adeogo.doctor, PID: 16526
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Boolean to type com.works.adeogo.doctor.model.TempMessage
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
        at com.works.adeogo.doctor.TestChatActivity$4.onChildAdded(TestChatActivity.java:362)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzbt.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6236)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You must provide the relevant code snippet where you are getting the problem.

Comment: TempMessage tempMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(TempMessage.class);
if (tempMessage != null) {
Message message = new Message(tempMessage.getId(), tempMessage.getText(), tempMessage.getCreatedAt(), new User(tempMessage.getUserId(), tempMessage.getName(), tempMessage.getAvatar(), tempMessage.isOnline()), tempMessage.getImage(), tempMessage.getVoice());
List<Message> teMessages = new ArrayList<>();
teMessages.add(message);messagesAdapter.addToStart(message, true);messages.add(message);}